# Leaflet Javascript: Layer Control Style in Internet Explorer Messed Up

Tags: leaflet

Please [see this link](http://gisdev.clemson.edu/ffliestemp/). Only in Internet Explorer the Layer's Control box/panel is expanded all the way across the screen. Here is the relevant code for the Layer's Control.

```
map = new L.Map("map",{
    center: [34.8, -82.0],
    zoom: 12,
    layers: [mapquestOSM, fireflies]
});

var baseLayers = {
    "MapQuest Streets": mapquestOSM,
    "MapQuest Aerial": mapquestOAM
};
var overlays = {
    "Fire Flies:": fireflies
};

layersControl = new L.Control.Layers(baseLayers, overlays, {
    collapsed: false
});

map.addControl(layersControl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I think I got it. Had to over-write the remote style sheet with this:

```
    .leaflet-control-layers {
        width: 150px !important;
    }
    .leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
        width: 150px !important;
    }
```